# Case insensitive search over email field as index in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, atlas

My collection of users (`user`) is indexed by the `email` field (and some other indexes).
Trying to find all documents that has an email that has an email which starts with a search term case insensitive (trying to implement serach-suggest logic).

I'm using the following query:

```
db.user.getCollection('user').find({
    "email" :  /^myEmail@gmail/i
})
```

As I understood, when using regex we are not able to use the index capabilities hence my query runs very slow.

Is there a way to implement such **starts with** search logic over indexed filed using MongoDB (or additional Atlas capabilities) leveraging the indexed field over large collection or should I use different technology for that matter?

**Edit**
Tried text indexes and it didn't work as I expected. Mongo text search treats `myEmail@gmail` as 2 different text tokens `myEmail` and `gmail` so I'm getting results matching `myEmail` and results matching `gmail`. It is not what I'm looking for.

Comment: Have your checked out the [text index](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/index-text/) to see whether it is helpful to you?

Comment: @ray, (edited original question as well) Tried text indexes and it didn't work as I expected. Mongo text search treats `myEmail@gmail` as 2 different text tokens `myEmail` and `gmail` so I'm getting results matching `myEmail` and results matching `gmail`. It is not what I'm looking for.

Comment: I would normalise emails to lowercase in the database. Then the anchored case sensitive regex can benefit from the index.

Comment: Also, see [$regex and Index Use](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v5.0/reference/operator/query/regex/?_ga=2.33833249.1448869912.1656297848-795770525.1649039239#index-use).